# How to reference CSS file so it can be found using an include in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php file which I want to include in various other php file and I am trying to add references to my CSS files but I'm having problems due to my directory structure.  Off the root folder I have 3 folders, admin, includes and styles.  The CSS files are located in styles folder and any files that I will include in pages are located in the includes folder.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to ensure my CSS files are found, at present if I specify the location of the css files based on the root the files won't be found from the pages in the sub folders. I've tried solutions I found online including  `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` without success and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or what else to try.  I'm completely new to PHP so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is my code.  Thanks

```
    <head>
<?php
    $server = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server . '/2025/styles/reset.css' ?>";
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server . '/2025/styles/normalize.css' ?>";
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server . '/2025/styles/characters.css' ?>";

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

The first is that using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` means you are relying on your server configuration. It probably makes more sense to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead for this. A list of all `$_SERVER` options can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

The second problem is that your HTML is not valid.
You are not closing your link elements properly. You are using a semi colon incorrectly, they should look as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server . '/2025/styles/reset.css' ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server . '/2025/styles/normalize.css' ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server . '/2025/styles/characters.css' ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `$server` variable and use a relative root URL. If the path to your file starts with a `/` that means to start at right after the domain and go under that path structure. For example:

Given this HTML element:

```
<link rel="/styles/reset.css">
```

- On the domain `example.com` it refers to a file at `http://example.com/styles/reset.css`.
- On the domain `whatever.com` it refers to a file at `http://whatever.com/styles/reset.css`.

The URL to the file is "relative" to the "root" of your URL.